# Snowflake 'ModuleNotFoundError' in EC2 isntance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, module, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using python version 3.8.10 and am needing the python connector for snowflake to write data out from an EC2 instance into a snowflake table.

I tried both `pip install snowflake-connector-python` and `pip3 install snowflake-connector-python` (installation was successful) and have `import snowflake.connector` at the top of my script, but I still get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake'` when trying to run it from the command line.

My python code is not running from within a virtual environment, but I suspect it is something to do with the snowflake module not being installed in the correct environment. How can I check this?

Comment: try this: ```python -m pip install snowflake-connector-python ```

Answer (score 0):

The modules you install with pip will be installed globally on your system if you are not utilising a virtual environment. Try executing the following command in your terminal to see if the snowflake module is installed globally:

```
python -c "import snowflake.connector"
```

If the module is properly installed, running this command shouldn't result in any problems. If you encounter a ModuleNotFoundError, the module has not been installed globally and needs to be done so.

It's likely that the snowflake module is being installed into a different environment by your pip command. The command to examine where the pip command is installing packages can be used to verify this:

```
pip show snowflake-connector-python
```

The snowflake-connector-python package's details, including the location of its installation, are displayed by this command. You must activate the proper environment before running your Python script if this location is not in the global site-packages directory.